# combination GRE problem 25

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, gre-exam

An appliance's model number consists of three alphanumeric characters. The first character must be one of 24 permissible letters of the alphabet. The next character is numeric, a digit from 1 to 9. The last character is also numeric, a digit from 0 to 9. how many distinct model numbers are possible?

Comment: Do you mean $26$-letters?

Comment: Welcome to math.se!  If you post your working so far and any ideas you have, people will be better able to give an answer which addresses your concerns.

Comment: @Nameless Maybe this is Samsung and they don't like one of the competitors so they disallow L and G from the model designations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to understand the solution is to draw a tree diagram. For each of the 24 letters you choose first, there are 9 possible numbers giving $24 \times 9$ different options. Now for each one of these $24 \times 9$ options of (letters followed by a number) there are 10 ways to choose the last the last number. Giving a total of $24 \times 9 \times 10$ options in total.

Answer (score 1):

If I am reading this correctly, this would mean there are

1. $24$ ways to choose the alphabet of letters.
2. $9$ ways to choose your numbers (count with your fingers).
3. $10$ ways to choose your numbers.

So by the Fundamental Counting Principle, there are precisely $24*9*10 = 2160$ combinations.